# How to test if a URL contains certain parameters with specific value using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an url in this format:

```
https://exemple.com/is/image/file/3221614006821_h_f_l_0?wid=80&hei=80
https://exemple.com/is/image/file/3221614006821_h_f_l_0?wid=100&hei=100
https://exemple.com/is/image/file/3221614006821_h_f_l_0?wid=1000&hei=1000
```

I need a regex to match the path and "wid=1000" and "hei=1000"

i tried this regex pattern but its fail

```
[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_?/(wid=1000&hei=1000)/]*)
Any thoughts?
```

Comment: Do you have to use RegEx? I would look into [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

Comment: yes i have to use regex

Comment: In which environment will this Regexp be used? Browser? Node?

Comment: Why do you have to use RegEx? Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of URLs where you want to extract the image dimensions you can do this:

```js
[
  'https://example.com/is/image/file/3221614006821_h_f_l_0?wid=80&hei=80',
  'https://example.com/is/image/file/3221614006821_h_f_l_0?wid=100&hei=100',
  'https://example.com/is/image/file/3221614006821_h_f_l_0?wid=1000&hei=1000',
  'https://example.com/is/image/file/3221614006821_h_f_l_0?foo=1000&bar=1000'
].forEach(url => {
  let m = url.match(/\bwid=([0-9]+).*?\bhei=([0-9]+)/);
  if(m) {
    console.log(url + '\n => wid: ' + m[1] + ', hei: ' + m[2]);
  } else {
    console.log(url + '\n => (not found)');
  }
});
```

Output:

```
https://example.com/is/image/file/3221614006821_h_f_l_0?wid=80&hei=80
 => wid: 80, hei: 80
https://example.com/is/image/file/3221614006821_h_f_l_0?wid=100&hei=100
 => wid: 100, hei: 100
https://example.com/is/image/file/3221614006821_h_f_l_0?wid=1000&hei=1000
 => wid: 1000, hei: 1000
https://example.com/is/image/file/3221614006821_h_f_l_0?foo=1000&bar=1000
 => (not found)
```

Explanation of regex:

- `\b` -- word boundary
- `wid=` -- expect `wid=`
- `([0-9]+)` -- capture 1+ digits
- `.*?` -- scan non-greedily until:
- `\b` -- word boundary
- `hei=` -- expect `hei=`
- `([0-9]+)` -- capture 1+ digits

Comment: @Digiprisme Digi: Does this answer your question? If so would you care to accept it? If not, please add some more details to your question.